# OpenCV calculation with complex Mat elements

Tags: python, c++, opencv, complex-numbers

I need to translate some code snippets using OpenCV Python bindings to C++ but I have some trouble with accessing complex values from cv::Mat.

`kernel = np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*A)`

This is the semantic equivalent using python bindings. Were `kernel` is a `np.complex_` typed numpy array and `A` another numpy array containing float32 values.

I search for something which does the same in C++, so I was trying to use:

`kernel.at<complex>(i, j) = exp(I*2*M_PI*A.at<double>(i,j));`

But it seems that I cannot access values from `kernel` with `.at<complex>(i,j)` because I get a

> Error:(145, 39) error: no matching function for call to 'cv::Mat::at(int&, int&)'

How can I access these complex values? Does anyone have some experience using cv::Mat in combination with complex values? I already read the OpenCV docs but I could not find something which matches with my question.

Thank you!

Fabian

Comment: Can you setup a [mcve]?

Comment: @Miki I will try to ask more generell: How can I modify a single element at position (row, column) in a cv::Mat containing complex values. Is there any equivalent to .at<double>(row, column) ?

Comment: How did you define your `Mat`?

Comment: `Mat kernel(rows, cols, CV_64FC2);` but maybe I have a wrong idea of Mat holding complex values .. I thought that a Mat can maybe handle std::complex datatype

Comment: try `kernel.at<double>(i, j)[0]` for real part, and `kernel.at<double>(i, j)[1]` for imaginary part

Comment: You should use the `cv::Mat_<complex>` interface. (The underscore is on purpose)

Comment: @manatttta thats exactly what I want ! :) Thank you!